# Palindrome Program output out of range

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming. Can you tell me why this outputs:

> string index out of range: -1

```
class Palindrome {

    public static String reverse(String s) {
        if (s == "") {
            return s;
        }
        else {
            return reverse(s.substring(1,s.length())) + s.charAt(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print(reverse("galskjdf"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZouZou there is no String comparison in this code, only substring, i don't see how this question is applicable

Comment: @Absurd-Mind How about `if (s == "")`?

Comment: lol, not a single day without this duplicate :-) I barely know Java but it seems like a design flaw to me, although I understand why it's not normal so many people fall on this.

Comment: @Bartdude This is not a design flaw. People need to know basic Java before programming, just as you are ought to know about pointers when dealing with C and variants.

Comment: @turbo The `endIndex` is exclusive. So `s.length()` is valid.

Comment: @ZouZou ah, I always get that mixed up about substring

Comment: @skiwi > I know, all languages have their specificities, but from my non-java point of view I find it very un-intuitive to compare strings and numbers with such a different syntax... All the languages I've worked with, although representing a very small proportion of existing languages, made it quite similar to compare strings or numbers. Well at least if I'm ever into Java I won't make this error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
class Palindrome {
  public static String reverse(String s) {
    if ("".equals(s)) {
      return s;
    } else {
      return reverse(s.substring(1,s.length())) + s.charAt(0);
  }
}

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print(reverse("galskjdf"));
  }
}
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java) might also be helpful (even though you probably did the above code as a programming exercise, it doesn't hurt to know that usually one would use already existing tools for this kind of thing).

The reason for using

```
"".equals(s)
```

instead of

```
s.equals("")
```

is as follows: In case `s` is `null`, the latter will throw a `NullPointerException` (because you try to call a method on `null`), whereas the former still works as you call a method on a "proper" string, see also [Gracefully avoiding NullPointerException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963936/gracefully-avoiding-nullpointerexception-in-java) However, I remember also some people criticizing this approach as this might make you miss the fact that `s` is `null` when it shouldn't be (in which case you should explicitly check handle that case).

Comment: `"".equals(s)` would be better to avoid a possible NPE

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing string comparison in a wrong way => recursion doesn't stop at the valid point. Replace this:

```
s == ""
```

with this:

```
"".equals(s)
```

**EDIT** Well, looks like proof is needed, here it is: http://ideone.com/TWm5U8

Comment: although this is not untrue, this doesn't answer the question; The error message doesn't come from this...

Comment: @Bartdude Well I tried the correction on the given code and it works ;)

Comment: @Bartdude you are wrong, proof http://ideone.com/TWm5U8

Comment: @Bartdude it's not where the error comes from, but it causes an invalid string to reach the else statement

Comment: @turbo why do you think it's not the source of error? =)

Comment: @nikis Bartdude said "the error message doesn't come from this" in which case he is _technically_ right, but it's due to an invalid input.

Comment: I admit I was wrong. I will switch the "-1" to "+1" ... but I would prefer the answer to mention the actual cause of the error more precisely so that if the OP ever get the same kind of error, he doesn't look for a bad comparison somwhere, but for a wrong substring index somewhere... Actually I can't change my vote without an edit...

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() <= 1) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return reverse(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
    }
}
```